# Cannot Login after configure oracle-xe

Tags: authentication, configure, oracle-xe

I already success install oracle-xe on my ubuntu 10-04, tried to configure the port and password `sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`, and then restart my computer and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex` and input `system` as the username and my password `admin` but it said that `Invalid Login Credentials`.

The problem here I cannot login, try to re-install the oracle but same problem occur. Anyone can help me with this things? I'm very appreciated your help, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that after I re-install again `oracle-xe` and set the password same with my system password it worked.